# is it possible to convert std::string into enum class in std::cin?

Tags: c++, enum-class

I'am new in cpp. Let's say we've got a class as follows:

```
 class Animal {
    public:
        enum class Group {mammal, bird, reptile};
    private:    
        Group group;
}
```

Now I'd like to initialise it in this way:

```
Animal::Group g;
std::cin >> g;
std::unique_ptr<Animal> dog = std::make_unique<Animal>(std::move(g));
```

I tried to overload istream as below and make it friend of `class Animal` but it doesn't work.

```
auto string_to_vlt(std::string const s) -> std::optional<Human::Violation>
{
    if (s == "mammal")     return Animal::Group::mammal;
    if (s == "bird")       return Animal::Group::bird;
    if (s == "reptile")    return Animal::Group::reptile;
    return std::nullopt;
}

auto operator>>(std::istream& is, Animal::Group v) -> std::istream& // friend function
{
    auto s = std::string();
    if (!(is >> s)) {
        return is;
    }
    if (auto result = string_to_vlt(s)) {
        v = *result;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

Comment: "_but it doesn't work._": How does it not work? `Animal::Group v`: That's taking the argument by-value. Do you really want that? Also, what value do you expect `g` to have if `auto result = string_to_vlt(s)` causes the `else` branch to be taken? Also, `std::move` move on an enumeration type does absolutely nothing and `Animal` can't be constructed from a `Group` the way you defined it. So `std::make_unique<Animal>(std::move(g))` should fail to compile.

Comment: I am not sure it is conceptually correct but I think  yes I do. My intention is to give a user the option to initialise it by typing the group of animal. That's the first thing which come to my mind. Is it wrong?
There is no fail in compilation

Comment: This is where a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) mapping table could come in handy. Try to steer away from "piles of `if` statements" as a problem solving method.

Comment: You are calling the `operator>>` overload with `std::cin >> g;` and it seems that you intent the function to modify the value of `g`. But you are passing `g` _by-value_. So you are just modifying a copy of `g` in `operator>>`. If you want to modify `g` in that line, then you'll need _pass-by-reference_.

Comment: There's not much point passing `v` __by value__ to `operator>>`.  You want to pass a _reference_ if you want your assignment to do anything useful.

Comment: Probably also a good idea to set the failbit of the stream if conversion is unsuccessful, too.

Comment: @tadman Would please tell me how can I use std::map to handle it?

Comment: @user17732522 thanks, u are right, I missed that point. I added & and it works now. Btw, now I see ostream is overloaded correct as I use it to visualise a value of the class member :)

Comment: @TobySpeight definitely :) thanks for your feedback

Comment: You can use `std::map<std::string, Animal::Group>` to map string labels to groups.

Answer (score 1):

There is cool library which address this issue [Magic Enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum).

It can make code work without extensive coding:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <magic_enum.hpp>
#include <magic_enum_iostream.hpp>

using namespace magic_enum::ostream_operators; 
using namespace magic_enum::istream_operators; 

class Animal {
public:
    enum class Group {
        mammal,
        bird,
        reptile,
    };

    explicit Animal(Group g) : group { g } { 
        std::cout << "making: " << group << '\n';
    }

    ~Animal()
    {
        std::cout << "removing: " << group << '\n';
    }

private:
    Group group;
};

int main()
{
    Animal::Group g;
    while (std::cin >> g) {
        auto dog = std::make_unique<Animal>(g);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ae7nbvbEq

Disclaimer: Note that this library leverages some compiler specific features, so there is no warranty that it will always work. See [limitations](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum/blob/master/doc/limitations.md#limitations).